# Recurring Contributions consistently stuck in Pending Status

Tags: iats

We've been noticing a trend over the last few months that typically around the 21-23 of the month several of our recurring contributions end up not being processed by iATS and then get stuck with a Pending status.  Where are the first places that I should look to figure out the problem of why there is this pattern?  We are using Civi 5.10.4 and iATS Extension 1.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

First place to look is to ensure your cron is running properly. The verification is managed by two scheduled jobs: one to pull in the journal from iATSpayments.com and one to the verify (checks the journal entries to see if any of your contributions have been completed).